# What's the pattern for what dimensions can be represented by a single number system?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

The real numbers can be used to represent a 1-dimensional space, the complex numbers can be used to represent a 2-dimensional space, but a 3-dimensional space cannot be represented by a single number system, though a 4-dimensional space can be represented by quaternions. I read that this is because an m-dimensional space can be represented by a single number system if and only if there exists a non-negative integer n such that 2^n = m. For instance, 1 = 2^0, 2 = 2^1, 4 = 2^2, etc.

There seems to be a contradiction though. In a 3D space, you can move east or west, north or south, and up or down. A 2D space is a plane where you can only move east or west, and north or south. A 1D space is a line where you can only move east or west. By logical extension, A 0D space is a dot where you can't move at all. And a 0D space could easily be represented by the set that only contains the number 0. This set is closed under addition(0 + 0 = 0), multiplication(0*0 = 0), and has all the field axioms. However, there is no non-negative integer n such that 2^n = 0. So what is the pattern? Is 0D just an exception to this rule?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "number system". If you just want addition to work, you can have it in any dimension. If you also want a multiplication that works nicely with said addition (you can expand parentheses and so on), and you want this multiplication to be so nice that, for instance, the equation $ax=b$ can be solved uniquely no matter what $a$ and $b$ are (as long as $a\neq0$, and where $a$ and $b$ are also part of the number system rather than scalars), which is to say, you want division to make sense, then you are a lot more limited, specifically only to powers of $2$.

Comment: Also, many (I would say most) consider $1\neq 0$ to be one of the field axioms, so the $0$ space is not a field.

Comment: @Arthur When you say one, are you talking about the multiplicative identity?

Comment: Yes. $1$ is multiplicative identity and $0$ is additive identity. Usually they are assumed to be different, just to avoid having to deal with that one case. It's a bit like how $1$ isn't considered a prime number. It could've been, but then we would almost always have to talk about "all prime numbers except $1$" and so on. For the same reason, we often assume that $1\neq0$, to avoid having to say "for any field with more than one element" all the damn time.